# Axioms of countability for countable conumerable topology

Tags: general-topology

I know that $(\mathbb{R},T) $ with $T$ the conumerable topology is not first axiom of countability (so it is also not second axiom). But I am wondering if the set $X$ where the topology is defined is infinite but countable  (such as $X=\mathbb{N}$), is this topology first or second axiom? Thanks.

Comment: Alright @Koro,so could we say it is second axiom because the number of open sets is countable (so the base of the topology given by the topology itself is countable). And then, it's also first axiom. Would this be correct?

Comment: I don't think that will work because set of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable (if it were countable, then the power set of $\mathbb N$ would be countable). I deleted my last message as I erroneously considered one of the separation axioms ($T_1$, in particular) in the deleted message.

Comment: Hint: Look at how discrete topology on countable $X$ differs from cocountable topology on $X$.